# Does we need to include an sdk file in iOS application for tracking GPS devices of Quectel M66

Tags: ios, objective-c

i m working on an App development of iOS currently working on gpsdevice tracking App. But confused in how to get started some say do find the sdk files of the device and import in your project some say you can go for protocols !!!!
But i want that all the longitude and latitude can be fetched on the network (without indulging database or indugling it) how?
Please do help me!!

Comment: Is that an external device? Else, CoreLocation is the framework to use.

Comment: Yes there is an external device !! can i use google map